# Should MuiTheme be a function or a value?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to find out what the value of the MuiTheme parameter for MuiThemeProvider in a React component should be. I inherited a code base, in which there are instances of MuiThemeProvider that look like this:

```
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';

<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <something>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Code Inspection tells me that `Method expression is not of Function type`. I think what it means is that I shouldn't have the parentheses in the theme; instead of `muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}` I should have just `muiTheme={getMuiTheme}`, but searching the Internet I find both forms in copious amounts. What is the right one? Should the value for `MuiTheme` be a function or a value? and if I may be so bold as to ask, can you please explain **how** you know this? I tried to find documentation of this "parameter" of the `MuiThemeProvider` and failed.

Comment: what version of the library is the code base using?

Comment: material-ui: 0.18.7, material-ui-icons: 1.0.0-beta.36, formsy-material-ui: 0.6.3

Comment: You should really look at upgrading to a newer version. I attempted to go back and look at source code for the 0.X release on github and it's not even viewable. So to answer your question, I'm not sure there is any good way to find the answer to your question. You will have to either find documentation for the 0.X release of material-ui or upgrade. I would HIGHLY recommend upgrading.

Comment: Thank you. I'll get to it eventually (I inherited a project with about 200 errors and 5000 warnings:)